# Simplifying click and toggle function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help making jQuery click and toggle function being simplified.

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f9LF5/1/)**

This is what I have:
**HTML**

```
      <div class="category-list-content">
                <h4><strong>Category</strong></h4>
                <ul class="category-list">
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="#">Company</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="#">Industry</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="#">Job Title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="#">Tenure</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="#">Seniority Level</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
         </div>
```

ABOVE are my main **category** list

```
<div class="category-list-sub-content">
            <h4><strong>Sub Category</strong></h4>
            <ul class="segmentation-list ">
                <p>Company</p>
                <li class=""><a href="#">9lenses</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="category-list ">
                <p>Industry</p>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Avation</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Software</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
             </ul>

             <ul class="category-list">
                 <p>Job Title</p>
                <li class=""><a href="#">UI Developer</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">UX Developer</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Designers</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Web Developers</a></li>
             </ul>


              <ul class="category-list">
                  <p>Tenure</p>
                <li class=""><a href="#"> 5 years</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">&lt; 5 years</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">&gt; 5 years</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">10 years</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">1 year</a></li>
              </ul>


             <ul class="category-list ">
                 <p>Seniority Level</p>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Team Lead</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Juniour Employee</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Intern</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Director</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">CEO</a></li>
              </ul>

        </div>
```

This are **sub-category** list.

I was wanting to make something like  when I click on the **Company** Sub category of Company will show and other sub-categories remain hidden. and when I click on the Industry , Industry subcategory will show and other will be hidden. Same goes for every category. Something like tab effect. I can do this by adding classes on each categories and sub-categories and giving .show() and .hide()  functions. but it will huge to add unique classes. Also I may add more categories and sub categories later. So is there any good way to make this work how I describe ? If you need to alter(add any class or ID) anything to make this work that will be fine.

Any help will be appreciated. I am really suffering with this.

Comment: So in reality you've got *nothing* !

Comment: Simplify as in write it for you?

Comment: My Intention was not to write code for me. I was wanting some hints. It's my bad I couldn't express well enough and I am sorry for that.
But I got only one suggestion what really helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is setting a #hash in every  tag of you category menu like:

```
<li class="">
    <a href="#company">Company</a>
</li>
```

Set the id corresponding on  in your "main category list" like :

```
<ul class="segmentation-list " id="company">
    <p>Company</p>
```

Then set an event on each  tag, detect the #hash and show only the right div.  A little research on something called the web could have helped you. I'm not gonna give you the complete code, try doing it yourself if you don't want other downvoting your question.

Comment: Sorry My Intentation was not to write code for me. I was wanting some hints like you gave me. I did mentioned I can do this with show and hide function. May be I couldn't Express well and I am Sorry for that.

Thanks for your Suggestion .

Comment: Well not a big deal but asking without any code is not really good seen on stackexchange ;).